# Jquery .each() .click() only getting data in last element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following to get the json for each member and create an element with a click listener.

```
$.getJSON('/api/members', function (membersJson) {
    $(membersJson).each(function (i, item) {
        $('#contacts').append('<div class="membercard">' + item.Name + '</div>');
            .click(() => show_details(item));
    })
});

function show_details(item) {
    $('#memberName').val(item.Name);
    $('#memberOcc').val(item.Occupation);
}
```

When a membercard is clicked it is meant to send its info to a more detailed div. However, when clicking on any of the dynamically created divs, only the `item` data from the last json in the loop is sent to the detailed view. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are binding and iterating inside a loop, this is to avoid in general, because the scope of the function will in the click, will take only the last element of the loop
Try refactoring like this:

```
$('#contacts').on('click', '.membercard', function() {
    show_details($(this).data('item'));
});

$.getJSON('/api/members', function (membersJson) {
    $(membersJson).each(function (i, item) {
        var div = $('<div class="membercard">' + item.Name + '</div>');
        div.data('item', item);
        $('#contacts').append(div)
    })
});

function show_details(item) {
    $('#memberName').val(item.Name);
    $('#memberOcc').val(item.Occupation);
}
```

Comment: I intend to add the click event to each dynamically created div, and not the `#contacts`. I've made an edit that hopefully makes that more clear?

Comment: With the above binding `$('#contacts').on('click', '.membercard',` for every new element that you add will take automatically the click event.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with JavaScript. Essentially, because the click event happens after the loop, the “item” variable is equal to the last item. To fix this, simply change:

```
$(“#contacts”).click(() => show_details(item));
```

To:

```
let _item = item;
$(“#contacts”).click(() => show_details(_item));
```

This creates a copy of the variable that will have the same value even after the loop completes.